# Export hive data to oracle using sqoop

Tags: hive, kerberos, sqoop, sqoop2

I was trying to export hive/hdfs data to oracle using sqoop on a kerberos cluster, but was unable to submit the job, and I'm not sure why.

I'm getting the following error:

```
2014-09-23 11:11:05 IST: FAILURE_ON_SUBMIT
Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Authorization (hadoop.security.authorization) is enabled but authentication (hadoop.security.authentication) is configured as simple. Please configure another method like kerberos or digest.
Stack trace: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.Acc essControlException): Authorization (hadoop.security.authorization) is enabled but authentication (hadoop.security.authentication) is configured as simple. Please configure another method like kerberos or digest.
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy13.getStagingAreaDir(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy13.getStagingAreaDir(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getStagingAreaDir(JobClient.java:1366)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to Authenticate to Kerberos using kinit.Also you need to do some configuration in hive-site.xml for Kerberos.Please refer these [link](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.5/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-kerb-2-3-3.html) and [these](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_9_1.html) for those configuration